# Docker nginx and php-fpm with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: image, docker, wkhtmltopdf

In the php-fpm container is wkhtmltopdf installed. Images are not displayed when I create a PDF. The problem is probably that the container cannot resolve the development domain (myapp.test). But I'm not sure if that's the problem. Does somebody have any idea?

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

wkhtmltopdf does not appear to be installed by default:

> root@1fc37ca5d512:/var/www/html# dpkg -l  | grep wkhtmltopdf
>   root@1fc37ca5d512:/var/www/html#

If your code relies on that, you may wish to expand your Dockerfile to include your dependencies.

Comment: wkhtmltopdf is installed. I can create PDF files but images are not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

To install wkhtmltopdf in your php-fpm image use following in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get install -y libfontconfig wkhtmltopdf
```